# Is there a required order for the execution of logout handlers?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

Im using Spring Security reactive with Spring Session Redis.
For custom logout handler, I read [Spring Security doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/authentication/logout.html).

```java
new DelegatingServerLogoutHandler(
    new WebSessionServerLogoutHandler(), new SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler()
);
```

Is there a required order for the execution of logout handlers?

In my project, if `WebSessionServerLogoutHandler` is executed first, will occur session was invalidated.
If `SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler` is executed first then it's fine.
Is that Spring Security's problem or Spring Session's problem?

Comment: The SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler must be before WebSessionServerLogoutHandler.

Comment: I found that,because i use spring session redis, the WebSessionServerLogoutHandler delete session id from redis,then SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler need to set context with key sessionid to null, but the sessionid has been deleted by WebSessionServerLogoutHandler.
So the SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler must be before WebSessionServerLogoutHandler.